# Input loses focus and each key stroke - TextField react-format-number

Tags: reactjs, react-number-format

I have created an input component (`InputComponent`) using `react-number-format`. This component accepts only a string numerical value with one decimal. Example: `"12.5"` or `"12"` but not `"12.55"`.
This works.

**However** when I use `InputComponent` to build another component (`BiggerComponent`), the input loses its focus on each key stroke.

https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-ishizaka-bvktl

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just solved it by moving the function that uses `NumberFormat` outside the Input function.
I think that if it is inside the `Input` function, the whole `NumberFormat` functions gets re-created at each key stroke. That's why it looses focus.

**Not** working example: (with the function that uses NumberFormat **inside** the Input function)
https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-ishizaka-bvktl

Working example: (with the function that uses NumberFormat **outside** the Input function)
https://codesandbox.io/s/great-snow-1h3ln